# openssl version issue on Mac OS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, openssl, homebrew, braintree

Recently, I'm shifted to Mac OS(Mojave) from Windows. I'm working on Django application. Its runtime python version is 3.4.3, so I downloaded and installed the specific version from `python.org`.

I installed the requirements for app. Here started the issue:

First, pip was not upgraded. So after some research I found the way to upgrade it via:

> curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3

and the reason using this. 
Then I run the server. One of my packages `braintree==3.35.0` is now having issue.

I've also searched for the issue, and some posts regarding this issue solves it by using `brew` to install python 3 to avoid openssl version issue, as my current python 3.4.3 has

> OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016

In my understanding from the solution posts, by installing python3 via brew installs the latest version for python3 and it has deprecated the support for specific version installation using its formula.
Also some posts advised to upgrade `request` package. But none of these resolved my issue.

My question here is, how to upgrade openssl version for python 3.4.3?

Whenever I try to install openssl using brew I get this:

> openssl 1.0.2q is already installed and up-to-date To reinstall
>   1.0.2q, run `brew reinstall openssl`

still the version is:

```
python3 -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

on using `brew reinstall openssl`

> A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the
>   SystemRoots keychain. To add additional certificates (e.g. the
>   certificates added in the System keychain), place .pem files in
>   /usr/local/etc/openssl/certs
>
> and run   /usr/local/opt/openssl/bin/c_rehash
>
> openssl is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
>   because Apple has deprecated use of OpenSSL in favor of its own TLS
>   and crypto libraries.
>
> If you need to have openssl first in your PATH run:   echo 'export
>   PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
>
> For compilers to find openssl you may need to set:   export
>   LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"   export
>   CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"

Unable to understand above. So help needed to understand the issue.

Comment: Did you download python 3.4.3 pkg installer from python.org?